# Enable nvidia driver in UEFI mode in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, uefi

I bought my laptop **Windows pre-installed**. After deleting Windows I didn't disable the **UEFI boot from BIOS** (doesn't exits any more). So I installed **Ubuntu 15.04** including **UEFI boot partition**. Everything was fine but after **upgrading to 16.04**, my **Nvidia driver** is not working any more. It's stuck on black screen.

After googling, I found out that **black screen** can be fixed by disabling the **UEFI boot** but in my situation I cannot disable **UEFI**. So is there any other way that I can use my Nvidia driver?

**Note: I have already tried nomodeset option. It didn't help.**

Comment: Try disabling secure boot rather then UEFI as it is unlikely UEFI is directly related to your problem.

Comment: To elaborate on bodhi.zazen's comment, Ubuntu 16.04 tightens its Secure Boot handling so that kernel modules must be signed; however, third-party kernel modules, such as those for the Nvidia chipset, are not signed and so will not work with Secure Boot active. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for some examples of how to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I disabled secure mode but no luck. It's same.    https://s6.postimg.org/hdqonufmp/IMG_20160818_231837.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As of 18.04 this (installing nvidia driver with UEFI) is done automatically by Device Manager (Read it carefully where it says to type password into MOK to add drivers, on restart. I missed it first time.)

For a DIY version of the same
[How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)
Although you may have to disable nouveau more forcefully by blacklisting it
https://gist.github.com/Rambou/c6769caee19b0b9915d8342b86c3ef72

You can check which driver your gpu is using with:
sudo lshw -c video
which will contain a line that says:
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
(or will say nouveau instead of nvidia if hasn't succeeded)