# How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

I found this post:
[nvidia-smi command not found Ubuntu 16.04 | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902636/nvidia-smi-command-not-found-ubuntu-16-04/903781and)

Which says that with UEFI secure boot enabled **nvidia-smi** could not be found in Ubuntu:

```
$ nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi: command not found
```

Any idea on how to enable secure boot with NVIDIA driver functioning?

I found this article on solving the secure boot issue with **virtual box**, just still have little idea on how **MOK manager** works:

[VirtualBox + Secure Boot + Ubuntu = fail | Øyvind Stegard blog](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/)

Comment: Why disabling “Secure Boot” is enforced policy when installing 3rd party modules
http://askubuntu.com/questions/755238/why-disabling-secure-boot-is-enforced-policy-when-installing-3rd-party-modules  Do you need Secure Boot? Torvalds clarifies Linux's Windows 8 Secure Boot position
http://www.zdnet.com/torvalds-clarifies-linuxs-windows-8-secure-boot-position-7000011918/
 the whole UEFI thing is more about control than security

Comment: Yes, kind of need secure boot. Do you think I can bypass this problem with **MOK manager**? I resolved secure boot issue with it on virtualbox problem

Comment: If anyone comes back to this after windows 11 upgrade, follow the next steps
1. Remove any currently installed nvidia drivers
2. Restart
3. sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX ( where XXX is the version. Currently it's 470 = nvidia-driver-470)
4. Set a password for the newly generated keys
5. Restart
6. Enable MOK
7. Type the password you previously set
8. Restart
9. Done

Comment: kudos @mike, it worked and my gpu drivers are working with secure boot

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

1. Download the latest driver from the NVIDIA website: https://www.geforce.com/drivers.
2. Create a new pair of private key (`Nvidia.key`) and public key (`Nvidia.der`) by running the command:

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY -outform DER -out PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Graphics Drivers"
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /home/itpropmn07/Nvidia.key -outform DER -out /home/itpropmn07/Nvidia.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Graphics Drivers"
   ```
3. Enroll the public key (`nvidia.der`) to MOK (Machine Owner Key) by entering the command:

   ```
   sudo mokutil --import PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   sudo mokutil --import /home/itpropmn07/Nvidia.der
   ```

   This command requires you to create a password for enrolling. Afterwards, reboot your computer, in the next boot, when the system asks you to enroll, you enter the password you created in this step to enroll it. Read more: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SecureBoot
4. For installing the NVidia driver for the first time, you need to disable the Nouveau kernel driver by entering the command:

   ```
   echo options nouveau modeset=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf; sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
5. Reboot.
6. Install the driver by entering the command:

   ```
   sudo sh ./XXXXXX.run -s --module-signing-secret-key=PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY --module-signing-public-key=PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY
   ```

   **where:**

   `XXXXXX`: name of file installer (downloaded from NVIDIA).

   `PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY`: full path to private key. If you place it in your home folder, use `/home/USER_NAME/` instead of `~`.

   `PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY`: full path to public key. If you place it in your home folder, use `/home/USER_NAME/` instead of `~`.

   **Example:**

   ```
   sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.67.run -s --module-signing-secret-key=/home/itpropmn07/Nvidia.key --module-signing-public-key=/home/itpropmn07/Nvidia.der
   ```
7. Done.

Read more https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.32/README/installdriver.html

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing when installing driver packages through apt? I may be wrong but I prefer enabling the relevant repos/ppas and then apt upgrade'ing.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this for Windows?

Comment: @Karsus Yes, look here https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/08/11/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot. It's relatively straight forward.

Comment: "This command requires you create password for enrolling. Afterwards, reboot your computer, in the next boot, the system will ask you enroll, you enter your password (which you created in this step) to enroll it."
My computer does not ask for any enrollment after I reboot. What is wrong? I followed every step given by @itpropmn07.

Comment: I just wanted to play games. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: This leads to a segmentation fault for me when running the driver installer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. Totally fixed my issues! I will add that my screen did go black with a blinking white _ cursor. I let it sit there for a bit and then did a hard shut off. Once I rebooted, the driver was being used!

Comment: Just to confirm this works for me on a dual-boot with Windows 10 using 545.29.02 drivers but needed to install the `libglvnd-dev` package.

Answer (score 6):

[The recommendation from itpropmn07](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049479/527764) works for me. There is one change I had to make which is the last step.

Instead of entering this command:

```
sudo sh ./XXXXXX.run -s --module-signing-secret-key=PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY --module-signing-public-key=PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY
```

I entered the command without `-s`:

```
sudo sh ./XXXXXX.run --module-signing-secret-key=PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY --module-signing-public-key=PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY
```

With this command I could interactively install the driver.

Comment: 2022 and I am getting `--module-signing-secret-key=~/.mok/Nvidia_key`. Any tips on this? I did remove the `-s`.

Answer (score 3):

I was also able to successfully install the drivers using the method by @itpropmn07 with one slight change.

The `mokutil --import` did not work on my ASUS motherboard so I had to import the key from inside the UEFI interface.

This can be done by loading the .der file onto a USB drive and navigating to the Secure Boot > Key Management section and selecting the *Append Default db* option.

A popup will then ask if you want to append the system default db. Make sure to select *No*, which will then let you browse to your file on the USB drive. Choose *key certificate blob* as the selected file type. Finally, save and exit.

You can verify that the import was successful by running: `mokutil --db`

Note: it would be wise to backup your secure boot keys and have them stored somewhere safe in case something goes wrong. Use the 'Save Secure Boot Keys' option for that. When restoring the keys, use *UEFI secure variable* as the file type.

Reference: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html#setuputil

Comment: I have a ASUS TUF laptop. I am not 100% through the process yet, but I was able to import it simply with `mokutil --import`. Maybe nowadays this importation might not be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have this problem when I update my BIOS, secure boot gets switched off and the enrolled keys get deleted. What works for me is to boot into Ubuntu with secure boot on, rebuild my kernel modules, reboot again, enroll the key, and reboot into Ubuntu. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/53562/610679) for a oneliner.