# Boot Message: pkcs #7 signature not signed with a trusted key

Tags: drivers, 18.10, signature

It seems that this bug is an old one, and a really persistent one, as has been reported by several users. It was also reported that the bug has been resolved in patch updates, but, somehow, I am still facing the same problem!

Machine: MSI GV62 7RD
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
Graphics: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.10
Kernel: 4.18.0-15-generic

Sorry about the limited details, but I am not Ubuntu expert (not a novice either).

I am filing this bug report as I was asked to file a new bug report.

Also, please note that I have already tried all the workarounds to this problem available on the internet (including disabling the Secure Boot from the BIOS as well completely purging and reinstalling the nvidia-driver-390), but nothing worked till now!

Expecting the Ubuntu team to resolve this soon.

With best regards,
Abbas.

**Edit: Found the latest driver, but couldn't install it!**

After looking at Nvidia's official website, I found out that the latest driver they have release is 410.93. After downloading the .run file, I proceeded as follows:

1. Purged all Nvidia packages, including nouveau, as well as xorg.
2. Made the .run file executable.
3. Stopped the gdm service.
4. Tried to install it. Got stuck here:
   [image]
5. Reinstalled all the dependencies of the driver package, as described [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/410.93/README/minimumrequirements.html).
6. Repeated steps 3 & 4. Got the same response.

The installer gets stuck at 5% infinitely until the terminal window is forcibly closed.

Any idea what's going on?

**Details!**

Every time I run the installer (.run file), I get this prompt:

*The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue?*

Does this hold any significance?

**Found the culprit!**

Although I had all the dependencies installed already, as mentioned earlier, something definitely wasn't right! With this thought, I rechecked each of the dependencies through the commands mentioned on the same [page](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.43/README/minimumrequirements.html). What I found was `glibc` could not be found, even when I had the latest version installed. I researched the internet and found that I am not the first one facing this issue, and the NVIDIA driver is not the first package making this mistake.

Actually, the NVIDIA driver was looking for `glibc` in

```
/lib/
```

While it was installed in

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

So, I solved the problem by creating a simlink, using the following command.

```
# ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

This allowed the installation to proceed beyond the 5% mark (where it was stuck, as reported in my last update).

**A bigger problem!**

Well, the driver installation proceeds beyond the 5% mark, but this doesn't lead to a happy ending! The installer concludes with the following message:

*ERROR! Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module.*
*Installation Failed!*

And..... I haven't been able to find a solution to this, yet!

**Reply to heynnema's reply #2**

I even tried the latest version (418.43) and that also fails with the exact same message.

**A good news!**

I think it must be reported that I do not see any `pkcs #7` messages at the startup anymore. Though I am not sure which of my *experiments* cured it!

**Another attempt**

I even tried the latest NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.56.run.

I would also like to mention that I am trying to install the drivers in *rescue.target* in order to avoid any conflicts with the running applications.

This time, the *ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module* message was accompanied with a bit more detail.

```
[227.245253] CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245255] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245258] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245260] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245260] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245261] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245262] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245263] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[227.245264] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
```

It would be really great if someone could help me with this NVIDIA driver installation!

Best Regards,
Abbas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module message was accompanied with a bit more detail.
```

The problem was solved by running the driver-installer (.run) file in **rescue.terget**, with **Secure Boot disabled**.

This successfully completed the installation. However, the **NVIDIA driver works only with secure boot disabled**.

**Keeping the Secure Boot permanently disabled definitely leaves the system prone to a lot of other threats and problems!**

[Link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048483/cuda-setup-and-installation/ubuntu-trouble-installing-the-latest-drivers-for-gtx-1050/post/5324194/?offset=7#5324830) to the NVIDIA forum post.

I appreciate all the help and guidance I received in solving this problem, especially from **heynnema**. I am really grateful.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled) post describes the procedure for signing the driver so that **it would work even with Secure Boot enabled**.
For an in-depth understanding, please refer to [this](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.43/README/installdriver.html#modulesigning).

Comment: Unfortunately, the driver doesn't work with Secure Boot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: assuming that turning off `Secure Boot` in your BIOS didn't fix this problem...

In the `terminal`...

`cd /var/log` # change to the syslog directory

`grep -i pkcs syslog*` # search syslog and syslog.1

Notice if it finds `pkcs` in which log file... syslog... or syslog.1

`sudo -H gedit syslog` # lets look at syslog

Search for `pkcs` in the log

Look a few lines before/after the `pkcs` line, and note which driver is called out

That driver needs to be updated or removed

**Update #1:**

```
Feb 20 00:22:57  gdm3[2133]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted 
Feb 20 00:22:57  kernel: [ 81.556911] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key 
Feb 20 00:22:57  systemd[1]: Stopped /run/user/120 mount wrapper. 
Feb 20 00:22:57  gdm3[2133]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted 
Feb 20 00:22:57  kernel: [ 81.687080] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key 
Feb 20 00:22:57  gdm3: Child process -2397 was already dead.
```

**Update #2:**

To view the extensive Nvidia installation instructions, **paying special attention to the kernel module signing information**...

Download the latest Nvidia driver 418.43 which was just released on 2/22/19.

`sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.43.run -x`

`cd ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.43`

`more README.txt`

`cd ..`

`sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.43.run`

**Note**: be patient when the installer is building the dkms kernel modules

Comment: It seems I found the culprit.

Comment: Feb 20 00:22:57 *** gdm3[2133]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted
Feb 20 00:22:57 *** kernel: [   81.556911] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb 20 00:22:57 *** systemd[1]: Stopped /run/user/120 mount wrapper.
Feb 20 00:22:57 *** gdm3[2133]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted
Feb 20 00:22:57 *** kernel: [   81.687080] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb 20 00:22:57 *** gdm3: Child process -2397 was already dead.

Comment: Have similar messages in both the files. Which clearly means that the kernel could not identify the nvidia driver to have a valid signature. Now, how to proceed now?

Comment: @AbbasMehdi  I'd first purge all nvidia related software, reboot, and make sure you have a 100% error message free boot. Then research online, I think there's a newer nvidia driver than 390. If there is, download and install it, reboot, and check for PKCS/whatever errors.

Comment: @ heynnema Sure I will!

Comment: Problem not resolved yet!

Comment: @AbbasMehdi give me more details. Did it boot clean without the Nvidia drivers? Did you later install a newer version?

Comment: @AbbasMehdi the latest Nvidia driver 418.43 was just released on 2/22/19

Comment: @AbbasMehdi please see Update #2 in my answer