# Boot hanging: A start job is running for Hold unt■ishes up (<counter>/ no limit)

Tags: boot, nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10. After the install, I was able to boot into the desktop, navigate over to **Software & Updates**, and install the proprietary Nvidia drivers from **Additional Drivers**. I rebooted after the installation of the drivers, and now it is hanging during the boot.

The few times I've been able to get out of the infinite loading dots and to the terminal output, I've seen this message (and it can go on for hours if left alone):

```
A start job is running for Hold unt■ishes up( <counter> / no limit)
```

[image]

**Which steps should I take next to solve this issue?**

EDIT:
This edit is to notify readers that I have tried the following:

- Adding `nomodeset` after `quiet splash` in the kernel boot line options
- Booting into an older kernel (in this case, `14.18.0-10 generic`) didn't work.
- Booting into recovery mode and fixing broken packages with dpkg

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Can you boot with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter? Did you install a bunch of SNAP applications after your install? Can you boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: Secure boot isn't on in my BIOS, `nomodeset` doesn't make a difference when placed after `quiet splash`, and booting into recovery mode and repairing broken packages doesn't work. AND completely reinstalling doesn't matter either (after installing the Nvidia driver again).

Comment: Also, booting up with kernel `4.18.0-10 generic` doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu partition? If not, I'll post the instructions.

Comment: What version Nvidia drivers? What model Nvidia card?

Comment: @heynnema GTX 670 with `nividia-driver-390`

Comment: Nvidia 418.43 is the most current for your video card.

Comment: `fsck` was showing a bad super block, e2fsck is saying the drive has a dos partition. I've used `fdisk` to reformat. Threw a GPT partition on it, and I'm reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema 418 might be the latest, but `nvidia-driver-390` is what is available in the Software & Drivers Additional Drivers window. It's tested. I've had a poor experience with Linux and manually installing Nvidia drivers.

Comment: After reformatting, installing again, same issue. I guess I'll reformat again and give the latest drivers a shot.

Comment: Not worried about `fsck` now, I just tried on a brand new hard drive. Same issue persists...

Comment: Have you verified that the .iso that you downloaded has a good checksum, indicating the it's a good download, and can properly be used to burn a DVD or build a USB flash drive? Which are you using... DVD or USB? Go to the download website, and download one of the "*sums" file, like md5sums, then in `terminal` do `md5sum filename.iso` and compare that number with what you see in the md5sums file, and make sure they match.

Comment: @heynnema This is on a bootable USB, and the MD5 hash checks out good on the .iso used

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page... the last time your reinstalled Ubuntu... it booted fine... and you did or did not reinstall Nvidia 390... and then it failed? Have you tried 418.43 yet?

Comment: @hrynnema the failure to boot only happens after installing the recommended Nvidia driver. I can boot in and use the computer just fine. Once I reboot after the driver installation, I get that start job running line, and that's only IF I manage to hit ESC before I'm looking at frozen Ubuntu boot up dots.

Comment: Also, I haven't tried 418.43 yet, I'll reinstall and try that now

Comment: Added `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and installed `nvidia-driver-418`, now I boot to a black screen.

Comment: The Nvidia drivers can be a royal pain. During/after the install, did you have to "register it in MOK"? I'm not 100% sure what that even is, but I think it has to do with security. Also, is secure boot off in your BIOS?

Comment: No secure boot, and I've never heard of "register it in MOK". :( I guess tonight I'll end up trying 18.04 out.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled and you might also search the Nvidia support forums for more Nvidia driver installation tips. I don't have to deal with MOK, so I'm not much help here. Short term, boot with `nomodeset` and at least you'll probably be able to fully boot.

Comment: I've been able to install 18.04,  install Nvidia drivers, and reboot without incident. I might just stick with the stable releases after all this.