# Unable to load NVIDIA drm

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I am trying to install Nvidia driver on my laptop , I have been following the step in ([How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)), and i have get to the last step. When i run the files, it failed and said unable to load Nvidia-drm .
What should I do now?