# Dual boot - Ubuntu 18.04 boots only when secure boot is enabled

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia

My Ubuntu 18.04 installation stopped booting normally lately - I can see only blank screen with a coursor in top left corner. But when I enabled UEFI secure boot options, the booting is complete. The blank screen also appears when waking up from the suspension and I have to reset my computer to be able to login to Ubuntu. I have the newest Nvidia drivers (440) and following grub settings:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

What may be the cause and how can I fix that? I'll be happy to provide any console output if needed.

Comment: Did you alter your Bios-Settings lately? Or updated it? Modern systems prefer UEFI against a legacy boot.

Comment: It's probably related to the nvidia drivers (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled. Sort of the opposite situation)

Comment: @s1mmel, Yes, I have updated to BIOS BNCN35WW recently...

Comment: check your BIOS, there should be something like SecureBoot or so? Try to check if there are different settings, which might help you get back grub. You can't destroy anything. If it doesn't work, or you problems running windows, change the settings back. Unfortunately every BIOS is bit different. But I knoiw for a fact, taht Ubuntu CAN use secure boot and has a valid UEFI-Signature.

Answer (score 0):

### Converting Ubuntu into Legacy mode

If Ubuntu is installed on a GPT disk (you can check it via the 'sudo parted -l' command), use Gparted to create a BIOS-Boot partition (1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag) at the start of its disk.

> Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB
>   location" tab. Untick the "Separate /boot/efi partition" option Click
>   the "Apply" button.

Go to your bios settings

> Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in Legacy mode.

**Also disable the fastboot option in your bios.**