# Nvidia driver uninstalls after reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

I installed the driver for my Nvidia GPU on Ubuntu 16.04 using this manual:

[How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)

However, when I restart, the driver seems to uninstall. When I put nvidia-smi in the terminal it comes back as not found.

I then went through the installation again as shown above (from Step 2). That works, but I don't want to do this everytime I reboot. (Right know I try not to shut down or restart, if possible.)

Is there a way to stop this from happening?