# How do I sign public and private keys for installing a driver?

Tags: drivers, uefi, 21.04, graphics-tablet

I am trying to use a Huion H640P graphics tablet to use with my machine that has Ubuntu 21.04 installed.

Surprisingly, the tablet works without any driver installation with Kubuntu 20.04.02 LTS, but the laptop does not even recognize the device in the Ubuntu 21.04 machine.

Anyway, I was looking into the unofficial drivers [here](https://github.com/Huion-Linux/DIGImend-kernel-drivers-for-Huion), as suggested [here](https://huionsupport.com/en-us/article/55-does-huion-have-a-tablet-driver-that-will-support-linux), in the Huion Support.

It [says](https://github.com/Huion-Linux/DIGImend-kernel-drivers-for-Huion#systems-with-secure-boot-enabled) that-

> Systems with Secure Boot enabled
>
> If your system has Secure Boot enabled, then the installed driver modules won't be permitted to load. You will see messages like "Required key not available". To make them work, you will need to sign them, or disable Secure Boot entirely. See documentation for your Linux distribution on how to sign kernel modules, or documentation for your computer's UEFI firmware on how to disable Secure Boot.

It says that "To make them work, you will need to sign them". I need to do this as I do not want to disable secure boot. Question is how do I do it?

I am absolutely new to this. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: "If your system has Secure Boot enabled" .... so disable it. It should be disabled on Linux and there is no need to read the remaining text. Could it be you had it disabled when using kUbuntu and now have it enabled? Because kUbuntu should ALSO not work when secure boot enabled. In case the answer is no... it is also unlikely that signing is the answer as we use the same core functions as kUbuntu.

Comment: How does signing work is my main question.

Comment: I was able to use CUDA without secure boot disabled without any significant hiccups.

I am trying to do the same with the Huion driver.

What are the implications of secure boot being enable vs. disabled?

Comment: This is the one you probably want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled "What are the implications of secure boot being enable vs. disabled? " it is a microsoft feature that is created to annoy creators of other operating systems than windows ;-) Or as they will claim: it prevents other parties to alter hardware signatures.