# Every week i need to reinstall Nvidia and VMware drivers when secure boot is on?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, security, vmware, secure-boot

I use Secure Boot, and every 1-2 Week, when i boot the computer the Nvidia drivers are not loaded and the VMware says that it needs to install some modules and afterwards gives an error about loading drivers and i have to resign their modules using the following article:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146460

And as for Nvidia Drivers, i need to reinstall the driver (and obviously give it my keys during installing for signing them) using the following:

[How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)

Now i understand VMware updates automatically and i need to resign their modules after every update, but i don't update the Nvidia drivers and they are already the latest version (510.60.02
), so what is happening with my Nvidia Drivers? Because i already had the latest version so it can't be that it got updated somehow right?

And why both of them (VMware and Nvidia drivers becoming not loading) Happen at the same time? Everytime this happen both of their drivers become invalid, so if this was an update, surely at some point only one of them would update and the other one would still work! So what is happening exactly?

So i feel like this is not related to Nvidia or VMware being updated automatically, as i already update them manually myself and always have the latest version, so its probablysomething else.

Comment: Sounds like you have automatic updates in place and, when there’s a new version of the kernel released, you need to go through the song and dance of getting these two things to play nice with the new modules 

Comment: secure boot is an attempt by windows to prevent bios malware and piss off all none windows users. A non issue on Linux if you abide by the general rules: do not install software from untrusty sources. The repositories are safe and when those ever do get breached ALL of Linux land will let you know. I agree: disable secure boot.

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers manually? If you did, depending on how, you may also have to update manually.

Comment: @Rinzwind  hmm not really, its always better to have more protection even if you abide by the rules, for example a zero day exploit being used (in browsers for example which happens a lot), in that case, you can at least make sure that your don't get infected by a UEFI bootkit, and therefore can detect the threat from a kernel module EDR..

Comment: @SorenA I'm sure the people that put a lot of work and effort into implementing secure boot   would find that sentence a bit disheartening..

Comment: @matigo So you are saying this is happening because of kernel getting updated, and not because of Vmware+Nvidia updates? If so, how can i make sure that when the update happens, the modules that i signed don't become invalid? I mean why would they become invalid after a kernel update anyways? I signed them myself and the keys are imported already..

Comment: @Nmath I did install them manually using the steps in the link that i provided, and i already have the latest version and do update it manually if a new version arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem where 470 and 510 keep coming up for update, replacing one another. The old one keeps coming back. One answer is to deactivate automatic updates, if that is a factor. There is something going on probably from Nvidia itself, because it keeps cycling the two drivers for my PC and now I just have to leave it ignored so it does not "update" me again to a lower revision.

Comment: Nope.  Not updating is bad. Far worse than disabling secure boot,

Comment: Yeah, except when your PC wants you to "update" Nvidia 510 back down to Nvidia 470. Then "updating" would be bad. That is what happened to me with the Nvidia drivers recently, maybe he has the same situation or related.

Comment: How can i make sure my problem is Nvidia trying to downgrade? Because when the problem happens, the drivers aren't even loaded and Nvidia-SMI commands don't work. And if the problem is Nvida Downgrading for some weird reason, how can i stop Nvidia from doing so? I haven't even added a third party repository and i am using the Ubuntu ones only, and i absolutely cannot stop updating, i update every day due to Security.

Comment: And if it is in fact happening because of Nvidia trying to downgrade, then why on earth this always happen at the same time that VMware gets an update? So weird, how are these two related? Surely there will be times that only one of them has an update..