# Ubuntu no longer recognizes my imported mokutil keys after i upgraded the kernel to 5.18, causing Nvidia kernel modules to not load with secure boot?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, uefi, secure-boot

I use Secure boot forcing kernel modules to be signed, and after i updated my Ubuntu 22.04 kernel to 5.18, i no longer can install the nvidia driver that can be download from here:

https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx

Tried the latest version (515.57) but still no luck. During the install, it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that
       differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA device(s), or no
       NVIDIA device installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.
       
Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for more information.
```

After looking at the logs, i found that its key is getting rejected:

```
Kernel module load error: Key was rejected by service
```

even tho i have signed it using my newly imported keys following this guide:

[How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)

And i tried to import a new key, sign them manually but still the drivers wont load because their key was rejected..

After i reverted back to 5.15, the drivers load fine.

So why is this happening? Why even after i   created a new key and imported it using mokutil (and imported it during boot), the kernel doesn't recognize the key and i  no longer can't load drivers that i signed with it?

Comment: Looks like I have the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Grief I think i just tried the software & updates -> additional drivers of Ubuntu and installed the Nvidia from there.