# Nvidia drivers broke after kernel updates

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

today booting ubuntu, after a few days, it asked me permission to apply some kernel updates. After i've done it and rebooted it started using llvmpipe instead of nvidia drivers, this causes my 2nd monitor to not work.
After hours of searching online i've found that a lot of people solved disabling Secure Boot in BIOS, but i can't because i'm using Windows 11 on another driver, and it requires it together with TPM.

I'm using nvidia 510 drivers, on my RTX 2060.
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Please note that (but i think that it is obvious) i'm still learning linux, anything needed ask and i will provide it.

Comment: How did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Software and Updates-->Additional Drivers
I tried even the .run script that is available in the Nvidia website.

Comment: Don't use the Nvidia script. Do use the drivers in the official Ubuntu repository. And if you can't disable Secure Boot then you'll have to use MOKutil to sign the drivers. That said your question suggests it was working before but it couldn't unless you did one of the aforementioned options.

Comment: I tried the nvidia script as a last resort, i always used the drivers in the repository via Software and Updates--->Additional Drivers. The drivers worked well before the update so i didn't try signing. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Yes, in particular the first answer to that question is what solved the problem.
Signing in that way the driver, rebooting, and enroll made the driver work with secure boot enabled. Even if i don't know how it was working before the kernel update, doing so made it work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as suggested by ChanganAuto was to sign the drivers.
I've done it by following answers and suggestions posted here: [How to install nvidia driver with secure boot enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled)

Big thanks to ChanganAuto for the tip that leaded me to research for that solution.

Comment: An easier solution I found years ago is to use the command efibootmgr to start from grubx64 instead of shimx64 but I am not using this anymore lately. efibootmgr -v will tell show you the boot options configured in your UEFI. To start from grubx64 you have to add a new entry identical to the existing one where \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi is replaced by \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi.